# Rails 4 log level resets to Debug, even in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, log4r

when I upgraded to Rails 4 my log level is always at DEBUG, even though I have `config.logger.level = Logger::WARN` in my production.rb

It was working fine previously on Rails 3.2, any ideas where might have changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the problem. you now need to set it via `config.log_level`

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb